# Change the background image of the preloading bar in Flex?

Tags: apache-flex

I would like to change the bacground image for the preloading bar in Flex, the one which appears before loading your application. [This article](http://cookbooks.adobe.com/post_Change_Background_Color_of_the_Preloader_Phase-1421.html) describes the way in which you can change the background-color, but is there a way to add a background image (and keep the loading bar on top of that)?

Comment: I think u r trying for the custom preloader with the Image and preloader for ex refer this http://pathfindersoftware.com/2008/08/custom-flex-3-lightweight-preloader-with-source-code/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for: http://blogagic.com/14/the-blogagic-custom-flex-preloader

Comment: I think so too. Taking a screenshot of the progress bar and imitating it as best as you can with a different background is the way I'd try it.

Answer (score 0):

The Adibe Cookbook you're linking already contains what you need. For example this recipe answers your question: http://cookbooks.adobe.com/post_Display_your_company_logo_while_you_application_lo-12756.html

Comment: Well, maybe I am wrong but I would like to keep the loaders itself just change the background (meaning, I just need to change the color appearing behind the flex preloader to a background - an image)

Comment: @user220755 I think that you are wrong. The way to do it is the one described in the link provided by moropus.

Answer (score 0):

Set the `backgroundImage` [style](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/core/Container.html#style%3abackgroundImage) of the application:

> **Type**: Object **Format**: File CSS **Inheritance**: no **Theme**: halo
>   Background image of a component. This can be an absolute or relative URL or class. You can set either the backgroundColor or the backgroundImage. The background image is displayed on top of the background color. The default value is undefined, meaning "not set".